# What is the context for this panel of Captain Marvel (Shazam) and a vibrating mechanical horse?

Tags: dc, comics, episode-identification, shazam

[image: "I'm going out for a few minutes! You stay on that vibrator till I get back." "Okay!" - Captain Marvel on a mechanical horse as someone leaves what looks like a gym]

So, I ran into this panel on a search some months ago, and got curious about the context. So I tried a Google search. Big mistake. There exist a completely different assortment of Marvel vibrators apparently. Reverse image searches didn't give me anything to work from, nor did attempts to restrict the breadth of the search.

Does anyone know what issue this comes from, and what the plotline was that explains why Captain Marvel has to ride a vibrating mechanical horse?

Comment: I tried to search for this and now you owe me $5 for a bottle of eye-bleach

Comment: @Valorum: I warned you... I don't even remember the context of where I first ran into this. It was another search for the site, and this one was one of the incorrect images returned for somewhat more innocuous search terms.

Comment: Googling for `"you stay on that vibrator till I get back"` reveals only this tweet: https://twitter.com/WeirdlandTales/status/887929393221324800

Comment: Search for shazam dc vibrator horse lead me to this https://i.pinimg.com/736x/51/7f/4d/517f4dfc93534a81de675040ef3b81eb--vintage-comic-books-vintage-comics.jpg

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cc/68/81/cc688127f698820283cc4b983f12db30.png - How bout a Mr. Mind tramp stamp tickle?

Comment: It could be a version of those old fashioned vibrating belt machines that were popular in the 1950s and 60s, which shook various parts of you and encouraged the fat to melt away. Pretty sure they don't work. I'm not certain why this particular model is horse-shaped though.

Comment: This reminds me of the iGallop, a piece of exercise equipment that's supposed to mimic a horse's gait to help you tone your core, like rockinghorse shoes.

Comment: This looks like it's from some time between the 40s and 80s artwork wise. Probably even limited to something to the 60s (although my old school comic art knowledge is poor). How many Captain Marvels can there really be to read through

Comment: OK. It's not Captain Marvel Adventures Vol. 1. I've been through all 150 of them and I've not found it

Comment: It's not Whiz Comics. I've been through all 155 of those.,

Comment: It's not The Marvel Family (Vol 1.). I've been through all 89

Comment: Wow. That is dedication.

Comment: It's annoying me now.

Comment: Not Shazam (1974) Vol. 1

Comment: NSFW and necrothreading, but considering you only have one panel: are you sure it's Captain Marvel? Penthouse Comix had a superhero team in which one character was a parody of Captain Marvel. This seems like the kind of joke setup they would use.

Comment: @DonFusili: Honestly, I don't know that it's Captain Marvel and not a parody. :) But there are a lot of panels out there that don't necessarily make sense without context (and a few that don't make sense with context) as http://www.superdickery.com proved.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Having a quick skim through the Penthouse Comix, no where near finishing them but the artwork looks a bit newer than the panel you've shown. Although I might be looking at an updated version.

Comment: Has anyone tried looking into Whiz Comics yet? That is his first noted appearance on Wikipedia

Comment: @Gothamite24 - I looked through all 155 of them. Unless I missed something, it's not in them

Comment: I'm not certain, but the fact that the red in this image seems to be off register (it looks like it should have been printed a smidge lower, hence the white areas on "Cap"'s legs) would imply the printing methods employed in comics at least into the early 1980s. I suspect that the printing methods used on a magazine with glossy paper may have been different. That said, of course, it's possible that such a printing glitch could have been added deliberately, for verisimilitude.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I did some diggings. As it turns out, that's part of the 21st page of **[Captain Marvel Adventures #82 - *The Streamlining of Captain Marvel*](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_Marvel_Adventures_Vol_1_82)**

[image: A page from Captain Marvel, on which the vibrating horse scene is happening. He's in a reducing salon, trying to lose weight, and some bad guys are planning to rob an oil refineries while he's kept busy.]

As it turns out, Captain Marvel was afraid he took on some weight, so he decided to burn up some fat. This can be seen on the previous page:

[image: The page of Captain Marvel that came before the one with the vibrating horse. The reason why he went to the reducing salon is because a thug paid children to call him fat. When the thug approached him to introduce himself as the owner of a reducing salon, he was immediately convinced.]

Comment: That's incredible! Myself and another user had put in many hours to no avail. Congratulations!

Comment: Well done. I must have somehow missed it on my look-through

Comment: @Valorum So I guess I owe you some eye-bleach then?

Comment: @Clockwork - I'm just glad *someone* found it.

Comment: "That you, Pete?  You sound completely different, and your voice is shaking as if you're sitting on some insane vibrating horse device, but I'll go on and re-explain our exact plan anyway."